# Present login screen from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I need to present a specific ViewController (defined in swift) from my app and it just doesn't work. Here is what I am doing:

I have a login screen defined in my storyboard in file Main.storyboard. That storyboard has a UINavigationController that segues into a screen with storyboard ID "LoginVC".

When I run the app for the first time, all is well. But when the user backgrounds the app (presses the home button) I am automatically logging off the user, which just means a variable "loggedin" is set to false in the userDefaults.

When the user presses the app icon to launch/foreground the app, it returns to the screen it was on when it was backgrounded, which is pretty standard behavior for an app but is NOT what I want here.

Inside AppDelegate applicationDidBecomeActive, I want to check the user defaults and see if we are logged in, and if not then I want to show the login screen "LoginVC".

My code is shown below. The code doe not throw any errors, but it never goes to the login screen - it just stays at the same old screen. What am I doing wrong?

Note also that MyLoginVC is defined in swift, so I imported -Swift.h int the AppDelegate.

Again, everything compiles, it looks like it should run, it thinks it is logged out and tries to show the login screen but it just.doesn't.work. Any ideas?

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{

    NSLog(@"applicationDidBecomeActive");

    BOOL loggedIn=[self.engine is_logged_in];
    if (loggedIn) {
        NSLog(@"self.engine says we are logged in");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"self.engine says we are NOT logged in");
        [self showLoginUI];
        NSLog(@"Are we at login screen yet?");
    }
}

- (void) showLoginUI {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    MyLoginVC *loginVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginVC"];
    if (loginVC) {
        NSLog(@"loginVC is something");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"loginVC is nil");
    }
    //
    // Neither of these works!
    //
    //[self.window.rootViewController.navigationController presentViewController:loginVC animated:YES completion:nil];
    //[self.window.rootViewController.navigationController pushViewController:loginVC animated:YES];
}
```

UPDATE: I can't believe I am the first person who ever needed to show a login VC when the app re-enters the foreground and detects that the user is now logged out. Maybe I can provide a  few more details. My storyboard is Main.storyboard, and the leftmost (initial) VC is a plain old UINavigationController. Is this automatically the rootViewController? Is the same rootViewController as self.window.rootViewController in the AppDelegate? Is there ANY way to have the app detect that the app just re-entered the foreground and must now show the login VC because the user was logged out when the app went into the background. Someone must have solved this before.

Comment: it is always a bad practice to put something like this in the _AppDelegate_, that file is not for that purpose; you can subscribe the notifications in one of your view controllers (or in the `rootViewController`), and handle every such situation there.

Comment: I don't understand how what you are suggesting would work. Can you give more details? When an app comes back into the foreground, it is on a screen other than login, but i want it to go to login. Yes i can send a notification and have my login vc listen for it, but the login vc is not the active vc so it won't exist in memery. How can a vc that is not on screen listen for notifications and show itself when notified?

Comment: you don't need to _send_ any notification, you need to _receive_ them only; I highly doubt your `rootViewController` does not exist, if that is the case, something is definitely wrong with your design-pattern. what idea I suggested is a much better pattern than you are having at the moment.

Comment: I never said my rootViewController does not exist. I said my login view controller would not exist in memory because it was probably deallocated. And it makes no sense to receive a notification unless that notification gets sent somewhere. Again can you please provide some details

Comment: so, your `rootViewController` can receive the notification about when it should show the `MyLoginVC`...

Comment: No because my rootViewController (as near as I can tell) is just a standard UINaviagtionController. When I look in the storyboard file, a UINavigationController is the leftmost VC in the storyboad, and it has the initial VC flag set in inspector, so I assume this is the rootViewController. How am I supposed to receive notifications in this? And more importantly, once I receive a notification, what code exactly am I supposed to use to show the LoginVC, which is shown as the next VC in the storyboard?

Comment: then, that would be a perfect timing to learn how to create subsets of a class for having a much better architecture for your project, I guess...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Through trial and error, patience, and lots of searching I stumbled across the correct answer, or at least a way that works. Here it is:

My storyboard has a UINavigationController at the top, which then connects to a LoginVC (I'm not much of a storyboard guy, and I didn't write the interface code, so I suspect "connects" is the wrong word but you get the idea). The UINavigationController has an inspector IF of @"LoginScreen" while the Login VC has an ID of @"LoginVC". The LoginVC class already properly handles the case of app launch and properly checks to see if the user is already logged in, transitioning to the main app screen if the user is already logged in. The case I needed to handle was when the user minimizes the app (by pressing the home button) and where I have overloaded AppDelegate applicationDidEnterBackground to log the user out.

When the user resumes the app (by pressing the icon), the app will enter the foreground and become active again. In applicationDidBecomeActive, I check userDefaults to see if the user is still logged in. If the user is still logged in, I don't do anything else. If the user is NOT logged in, I call my own AppDelegate function showLoginUI to tell the app to switch to the login interface. Here is that function:

```
-(void) showLoginUI {
    self.window.rootViewController = [self.window.rootViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginScreen"];
}
```

This one line of code inside that function is the only thing I needed to do, and it worked like a charm. It looks like it sets the window rootViewController to a newly instantiated UINavigationController that is the root VC in the storyboard. Not sure what magic is going on under the hood but it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

To me, pushing this viewController to the top of the stack seems wrong. I would try to pop the other viewControllers off the stack until I was back at the loginVC. UINavigationController provides a very convenient method for this:

```
[self.window.rootViewController.navigationController popToViewController:savedLoginVC animated:NO];
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/popToViewController:animated:

Comment: Nice suggestion, but sadly it doesn't work. Same result - the existing VC just sits there, no switch to the login VC. I tried using the login VC I got from the storyboard as in my original code, and I even tried using a saved version that I saved from whenever the login VC was originally loaded. Neither works.

Comment: Just as a test, can you call popViewController on the navigationController? And does it pop the top viewController?

Comment: No that doesn't do anythoing, just shows the same screen. When I backgroun the app again I get this: Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates.

Answer (score 0):

When your application come back from background to foreground. Then whatever action you want to perform write that code in

AppDelegate -> applicationWillEnterForeground method

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application 

{
// Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}
```

Comment: No that doesn't work. That method is called before applicationDidBecomeActive anyway, so doing it here doesn't help.